# Dplyr function with optional default argument and required ellipiss

Tags: r, function, dplyr, ellipsis, rlang

I've a simple function that adds counts for unique combination of variables:

## Function

```
# Add tally summary for group
add_tally <- function(df, n = "n", ...) {
  # Grpup variables
  group_vars <- rlang::quos(...)

  # Check if ellipsis is empty
  if (length(group_vars) == 0) {
    stop("Missing grouping variables")
  }

  none <- Negate(any)

  # Check that passed object is data frame or tibble
  if (none(tibble::is_tibble(df), is.data.frame(df))) {
    stop("Passed object should be a data frame or tibble.")
  }

  if (hasArg("n")) {
    # Take varname
    varname <- n
  } else {
    varname <- "n"
  }

  df %>%
    group_by(!!!group_vars, add = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(!!varname := sum(n())) %>%
    ungroup()

}
```

### Example

It's fairly straightforward:

```
>> mtcars[,c("am", "gear")] %>% add_tally(n = "my_n", am,gear)
# A tibble: 32 x 3
      am  gear  my_n
   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1  1.00  4.00     8
 2  1.00  4.00     8
 3  1.00  4.00     8
 4  0     3.00    15
 5  0     3.00    15
 6  0     3.00    15
 7  0     3.00    15
 8  0     4.00     4
 9  0     4.00     4
10  0     4.00     4
```

## Problem

I would like for the **`n`** argument to be optional. I.e. if not explicitly defined *(as `my_n` in the example above),* I would like for the argument to take default ***`n`*** value. As it would usually happen with *`n = "n"`,* which is now redundant due to attempted `hasArgs()` call.

### Example

This fails:

```
>> mtcars[,c("am", "gear")] %>% add_tally(am,gear)
Error in add_tally(., am, gear) : object 'am' not found
```

#### Desired results

```
# A tibble: 32 x 3
          am  gear  n
       <dbl> <dbl> <int>
     1  1.00  4.00     8
     2  1.00  4.00     8
     3  1.00  4.00     8
     4  0     3.00    15
     5  0     3.00    15
     6  0     3.00    15
     7  0     3.00    15
     8  0     4.00     4
     9  0     4.00     4
    10  0     4.00     4
```

Comment: just change the order of your parameters `add_tally <- function(df, ..., n = "n")`

Comment: @JulienNavarre Correct, if you want to make it an answer I will be happy to accept.

Comment: @akrun TBH, not many practical reasons behind this function. I want to make better use of quosures and `rlang` as such, a lot things are pointless there like `none <- Negate(any)`.

Comment: Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334322/how-to-deal-with-ellipsis-in-the-presence-of-optional-arguments)

Comment: @akrun Thanks very much for the informative link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the order of your parameters so the 2nd parameter you give isn't interpreted as the `n` value if it's unnamed.

```
add_tally <- function(df, ..., n = "n") {
 #function code
}
```